# Rails/Ruby NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x718c278>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, runtime-error

I want to execute the following:

case 1:

```
x = Group.all[0].people
x.class
=> Array
x.order
```

fine.
:)

case 2:

```
y = Person.all
y.class
=> Array
y.order
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x718c278>
```

:(

Both x and y contain the same type of item -  bunch of Person models.
Why can't ruby order the array?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: version of rails ? also all method will fire the query. so you cannot apply order, in the Group class or Person, you can apply order, which will fire a sql with order

Comment: I need to execute people.order("upper(last_name), upper(first_name)") where people is the array. So what's the equivalent with sort?

Comment: The first ans second snipper both will return nomethoderror right ?

Comment: x.order works, y.order does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the Rails 3 the method [all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-all)([GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c9f27e3a479e17cd94248c007e4f528026bc18f6/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L158)) returns an array. It can't be ordered with order method.

Although you may use the [sort](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000423) method do to the ordering.

The `people` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that can then be further scoped.

Fortunatelly the `ActiveRecord::Relation` have the `to_a` method that will return an array that you may sort.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so Group.all.first.person does not return an Array. It looks like it does, but really it's part of ActiveRecord AREL that allows you to chain together relationships and scopes.

When you call `#order` on the `Group.all.first.person` you are really calling the "order" scope, telling the query to order person on nothing.

You will get the same error if you call

```
Group.all.first.person.all.order
  NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x007fe7dd03ff08>
```

It's the "#all" that matters.

In ruby, there is no "order" method. There is a sort and sort_by